# Golang HTTP POST succeeds, but it doesn't invoke a docker action

Tags: sockets, http, docker, go

Problem: Although I can easily issue GET and POST commands from curl on my local docker socket, when I try to do the POST equivalent in Golang for a docker pull action,  using `net.Dial`, I see no action taken on Docker's behalf.

Note that, meanwhile, the `GET` action works just fine using docker sockets via the golang client.

For example, when running the code at the bottom of this post, I see:

```
2018/01/05 14:16:33 Pulling http://localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=fedora&tag=latest ......
2018/01/05 14:16:34 Succeeded pull for http://localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=fedora&tag=latest &{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Docker-Experimental:[true] Ostype:[linux] Server:[Docker/17.09.0-ce (linux)] Api-Version:[1.32] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Fri, 05 Jan 2018 19:16:34 GMT]] 0xc42010a100 -1 [chunked] false false map[] 0xc420102000 <nil>}
```

The code for attempting to do a pull via a POST action:

```
// pullImage is the equivalent of curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http://localhost/images/create?fromImage=alpine
func pullImage(img string, tag string) (err error) {
        fd := func (proto, addr string) (conn net.Conn, err error) {
                return net.Dial("unix", "/var/run/docker.sock")
        }
        tr := &http.Transport{
                Dial: fd,
        }
        client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
        imageUrl := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=%s&tag=%s", img, tag)
        log.Printf("Pulling %s ......  ", imageUrl)
        resp, err := client.Post(imageUrl, "application/json", nil)
        if resp.StatusCode == 200 && err == nil {
                log.Printf("Succeeded pull for %s %v",imageUrl, resp)
        } else {
                log.Printf("FAILED pull for %s , ERROR = ((  %s  )) ",imageUrl , err)
        }
        return err
```

Question:

What does `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http://localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=fedora` do differently then the Golang code in the above snippet?

Comment: What does "I see no action taken on Docker's behalf." mean? What do you expect to see? Also, have you looked at the json response? It may contain useful information.

Comment: And always check the error before the response, or you will panic.

Comment: A good debugging step is to stick a logging proxy (e.g., `socat` with an appropriate command line) between your code and Docker. Does the request from your golang code look the same as the request from `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  Actually, my prolem was that I wasn't completing the response body.

Adding

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

after the `rest, err := client...` clause was enough to finish triggering an entire pull.  Not quite sure why closing the response body effects the ability of docker to start pulling the images down, but in any case, that was the case.

Comment: It's probably waiting to write the body, but you were never reading it, and closing the connection forced the request to complete. Always read the response body if you want to complete the request and be able to reuse the connection.